# how to unhook in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, storyboard

Simple Question: How can I unhook this:
[image: IB hook]

I copy-paste a Viewcontroller between projects and IB do not unhook automatically -> that means I have two hooks between projects and storyboards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]Go to interface builder, right click on the view that you want to unhook and on the referencing outlets section click on the (x) button that will appear next to the IBOutlet.

Comment: If i do this it will unhook the previous project too

Comment: When you copy-paste the files make sure that is copied not just added to the project. ;)

Comment: I did it with cmd+c and cmd+v. Is it copied? or just added?

Comment: You have copied it. If you unlink it here, it will only unlink in *this* project. Your other project will not change.

Comment: Okay. I was a bit confused that copying automatically hooks the old storyboard and it have to unhook and so on.